# What's an easy way to compare a javascript time string in an sql query

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am using Moment JS to create a date to compare to a field in SQL.

My MaxEditDate variable

```
var MaxEditDate = moment().subtract(3,'years').format("YYYY-MM-DD H:m:ss");
```

Is being compared as is without any success of course in an MS SQL query.

```
tblLabReport.dtCreated >= ${locMaxEditDate}
```

Is there an easy way of comparing sql dates to a javascript string date object ?

Thanks.

Comment: You're using any ORM? Normally we use just the date without time to find a row filtred by date in databases, Checkout how the date are stored on database before query

Comment: Have you tried passing a value, something like: var d = new Date("2015-03-25T12:00:00Z"); Check if the value has the same format as the value you send to the database.